# Functions commute with a given polynomial

Tags: functions, polynomials

Given a polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbb{C}[x]$,how to find(describe) functions(smooth or continuous or polynomial) that are commute(under composition) with $f(x)$?

There are trvial ones :$x,f,f\circ f,f\circ f\circ f$,....Are there any other functions commute with $f(x)$?We may take $f(x)=x^2+x$ for example.

Comment: You seem to imply commuting with respect to function composition.  If so, specifying this would improve the Question and its title.

Comment: See here, (Theorem 1.2) http://nyjm.albany.edu/j/2007/13-5p.pdf

Comment: @ Kelenner:thanks,the reference is helpful!