# Functions commuting with the given polynomial.

Tags: functions, polynomials, continuity, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose that we are given a polynomial

$$
f(x) \colon= a_0x^n + a_1x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_{n-1}x + a_n,
$$
where $a_i \in {\Bbb R}~ {\mathrm{or}}~{\Bbb C}$. Then it would be asked that

Q. What is the characterisation (possibly understandable or reasonable) of the function $g(x)$ such that $f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$ holds?

Originally I stumbled into the question posed on a certain website, which asks the relations between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ when $f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$ holds.

Then, I got an idea of determining $g(x)$ once $f(x)$ is given with a polynomial. This will help proceed with the generalisation, for Weierstrass theorem ensures the uniform approximation for an arbitarary continuous functions by polynomials.

Comment: This has been asked before, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937894/functions-commute-with-a-given-polynomial), and see the reference there.